# Postgres master / slave based on table

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

Currently I have 1 postgres instance which is starting to receive too much load and want create a cluster of 2 postgres nodes.

From reading the documentation for postgres and pgpool, it seems like I can only write to a master and read from a slave or run parallel queries.

What I'm looking for is a simple replication of a database but with master/slave based on which table is being updated. Is this possible? Am i missing it somewhere in the documentation?

e.g.

```
update users will be executed on server1 and replicated to server2
update big_table will be executed on server2 and replicated back to server1
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called MASTER/MASTER replication. This is supported natively (without PgPool) since 9.5. Note, that it's an "eventually consistent" architecture, so your application should be aware of possible temporary differences between the two servers.

See PG documentation for more details and setup instructions.